# Код не переходит в функцию с декоратором @bot.message_handler()

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет! Создаю двух-язычного (ru, en) тг бота. *Ниже часть кода с проблемой:*

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def colors(message):
    global mood
    if message.text == 'Весёлое ' or message.text == 'Happy ':
        mood = 'happy'
        text = f'Отлично! Настроение картинки - <b>{message.text}</b>. Теперь выберите основной цвет картинки из плиток в низу экрана.'
        if message.text == 'Весёлое ':
            markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
            btn1r = types.KeyboardButton('Оранжевый ')
            btn2r = types.KeyboardButton('Красный ')
            btn3r = types.KeyboardButton('Жёлтый ')
            btn4r = types.KeyboardButton('Розовый ')
            btn5r = types.KeyboardButton('Зелёный ')
            markup1.row(btn1r, btn2r, btn3r)
            markup1.row(btn4r, btn5r)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)
        else:
            text = translator.translate(text, src='ru', dest='en').text
            markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
            btn1e = types.KeyboardButton('Orange ')
            btn2e = types.KeyboardButton('Red ')
            btn3e = types.KeyboardButton('Yellow ')
            btn4e = types.KeyboardButton('Pink ')
            btn5e = types.KeyboardButton('Green ')
            markup1.row(btn1e, btn2e, btn3e)
            markup1.row(btn4e, btn5e)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def pictures(message):
    print('pictures')
    if message.text == 'Оранжевый ': 
        pass
    elif message.text == 'Красный ':
        pass
    elif message.text == 'Жёлтый ':
        pass
    elif message.text == 'Розовый ':
        pass
    elif message.text == 'Зелёный ':
        pass
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Дело в том, что в моей задумке, при нажатии кнопки с любым цветом код должен выполнять функцию `pictures`. В ней даже есть `print('pictures')`, чтобы понять, работает ли она. Но **она не работает**! *Подскажите, как это пофиксить?*